# Return data to Blade with foreach loop in controller

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, controller

I have categories and posts. I want to make each post line up for each other's category. The following is the code that I tried in the controller. Then I call in Blade with a foreach loop.

```
$smallpostsWithCat = array();
$postsWithCat = array();

$postsWithCatQuery = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('post_translations', 'posts.id', 'post_translations.post_id')
    ->join('language', 'post_translations.language_id', 'language.id')
    ->where('language.local', App::getLocale())
    ->where('big_thumbnail', 1)->latest('post_date')->limit(1)->get();

$smallpostsWithCatQuery = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('post_translations', 'post_translations.post_id', 'posts.id')
    ->join('language', 'post_translations.language_id', 'language.id')
    ->where('language.local', App::getLocale())
    ->where('big_thumbnail', null)->latest('post_date')->limit(2)->get();

foreach ($cate as $item) {
    foreach ($postsWithCatQuery as $data) {
        if ($item->category_id == $data->category_id)
            $postsWithCat[] = $postsWithCatQuery;
    }
    foreach ($postsWithCatQuery as $data) {
        if ($item->category_id == $data->category_id)
            $smallpostsWithCat[] = $smallpostsWithCatQuery;
    }

}
```

```
       @foreach($postsWithCat as $post_b)
                                <!-- Small Post Start -->
                                    <div class="post sports-post post-separator-border">
                                        <div class="post-wrap">

                                            <!-- Image -->
                                            <a class="image" href="{{route('front.post_view', [$post_b->post_id])}}"><img
                                                    src={{$post_b->image}}
                                                        alt="post"></a>

                                            <!-- Content -->
                                            <div class="content">
```

Comment: Are you asking about [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)?

Comment: I think you should share some data of posts and some better explanations, because it's not clear what smallpost and lining up mean.

Comment: maybe you're looking for groupBy with category_id

Comment: Thx Psycho it did work that